# Items do not have dynamic height inside Scrollable Columns in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Items seem to have fixed height inside `Column`.

I'm trying to show multiple rows of dynamic height inside the column, and the items of those rows also having dynamic height.

I have tried wrapping the `Column` inside the box, but that doesn't work.

```
 Box {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.background_home),
            contentDescription = "",
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(0.3f)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        List()
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "My Days",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            )
            Text(text = "Red Sun")
        }
        MyAnotherList(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(0.6f)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "My Other Days",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Monospace,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            )
            Text(text = "Blue Sun")
        }
        MyOtherList()
    }
    TopBar()
}
```

Trying to achieve something like this, but all the rows will have dynamic height

[image]

Is there a way that I can provide dynamic height to the items inside scrollable columns.

Comment: Please format the question correctly.